# C linked lists - deleting element

Tags: c, list, element

if I have a linked list in C and I need to write a function that will delete one of it's elements in the the list (not the first or last one). The list is a global variable, so anywhere I use it it will be changed. If I do a `while` loop to get to the correct spot and then delete the element, wont the whole list change because I had to move the head to that point?

While doing `head = head -> next` in the while loop, the pointer is moving element by element and I have no way of going back to the first element once I have finished. 
So how can I delete an element without erasing part of the list?

Comment: Please show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: You will need to use a varaible for the operation. Something like `List* seek = head; seek = seek -> next`

Comment: Roughly you need to so something like this: `head = head -> next;` -> `previous = head; head = head -> next;`. BTW: did you google the exact title of your question?

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset But if I use a variable to save the list then I only deleted the element from the temp variable, not from the real list.

Comment: @eitanmayer no. The references inside the list are changed permanently.

Comment: You **never** walk a list by modifying a global variable. Always use local variables for walking.

Comment: @eitanmayer check my answer

Comment: @eitanmayer please show your actual code, even if it's partially wrong. Then we don't weed to make assumptions about your code.

Comment: Ohh I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have any code yet, it was just something that I didn't understand how to do

Comment: Hope I explained it simply enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't move the global head but rather make a new pointer that will work as a temporary head while iterating through the list.

Lets say the list looks like:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

If you want to delete C for example, you need to iterate to B (and see that it points to C). Then save it's pointer to C lets call it `pC`, move on to C and save it's pointer to D lets call it `pD`.

Then you can simply re-link the list by doing `pC = pD` so that B now links to D and skips C entirely. That way you remove an element from a linked list.

Your new list will be `A -> B -> D`.

Just remember to dump the variable before you lose the pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Two options, off the top of my head :

- Have the last element point to the first element. This way, no matter what node of your linked list you delete, you can always "go back".
- Always keep a reference to your first element.

This being said, I don't think having a linked list as a global is a good idea ; is there no other way? Furthermore : is a linked list the right thing for what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a project and the linked list is given beforehand.. But thanks this helped