# How to remove adjacent pair in linked list

Tags: c++

```
void remove_adjacent_pair (LN<T>*& ll)   // remove the adjacent two values if they are equal
{
    if (ll == nullptr)
        return;
    for(LN<T>* p = ll; p -> next != nullptr; p = p-> next)
    (
        if(p -> value == p -> next -> value)
        {
            if (p == ll)
            {
                ll = p -> next -> next
            }
            else
            {
                LN<T>* to_delete = p;
                p = p -> next;
                delete to_delete;

                LN<T>* to_delete2 = p;
                p = p -> next;
                delete to_delete2;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

How do I remove the adjacent pair in a linked list? Assuming that I want to remove the adjacent pair which has the same value.

Can someone help me to fix my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C linked lists - deleting element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46729946/c-linked-lists-deleting-element)

Comment: writing in the title "not a duplicate" is very redundant and serves no purpose. We understand that you do not consider it a duplicate, otherwise you wouldn't have asked the question. However, others might see it as a duplicate and tag it. It doesn't mean it _is_ a duplicate - that's why there needs to be 5 votes to actually make it a duplicate.

Comment: If you are worried that your question will be closed due to the linked question explain _in your question_ why you do not consider it that way. You can find more information regarding that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

What you did is *almost* correct. You just have to make sure that the function parameter gets updated properly:

```
LN<T>* to_delete = p;
LN<T>* to_delete2 = p->next;
ll = to_delete2->next; // update ll so the list is still usable after returning
delete to_delete;
delete to_delete2;
```

Comment: Hi, I got the " exit with code 0" when I tried to iterate through 1->2->3->3->4->nullptr. And the debug shows "variables are not available".

Comment: If 'code 0' is the exit value of your main function, that means success, so is not indicative of a problem. And if your application has exited, then of course you aren't going to be able to inspect your variables in the debugger any more...